# Is there any real time log monitoring for Apache2 (WAMP)?

Tags: windows, apache, monitoring

I'm looking for a desktop app (win32 or 64) that can monitor visits and display realtime info (like current connected users, location ...) off a apache2 win32 ? Is there such a software?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any apps like that, but I know Google Analytics launched Real-time visitor, so that might do it for you!